# Divide all columns of a dataframe by a smaller one by key without merging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, division

I know this is a well-asked question, but I am searching from quite some time and cannot find the answer.

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID.  denominator
A     2
B     4
C     5
```

and another one like this:

```
ID.  Value1.   Value2.  Value3.  Value4  ...
A     2.        1.       4        8.     ...
B     4         2        6        0      ...
C     5.        5        7        7      ...
```

And I want to divide all columns from the first dataset by the second dataset based on the ID and replace the value on the second dataset with this answer of the division.

Also, the datasets are big, so I don't want to do it by merging and then dividing, as in some answers.

Datasets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID.':list('abc'),
        'denominator':[2, 4, 5]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID.':list('abc'),
         'var2':[1,0.5,7],
         'var3':[7,8,9],
         'var1':[1,3,1]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_index`:

```
df2.set_index('ID.').div(df1.set_index('ID.')['denominator'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Actually this do not work. It divides the 'ID.' as well and also just returns NAN. I update my question with the code of the datasets so you can test and see

Comment: Great, now it worked! Can you explain me why the axis=0 made the trick?

Comment: `axis=1` is default, and it would divide row-wise. `axis=0` divide column-wise. Pandas will align index for division, so row-wise operation gives all `nan` as the index and columns are totally different.